# Как передавать микро разметку на странице с некоторым количеством постов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, facebook

Есть страница на которой 10 постов. На странице каждого поста предельно понятно как в мета тегах передать разметку. А как это сделать если постов 10 и на каждом есть кнопка поделиться ?

Comment: Приведите может пример какой...

Comment: Так вы делайте кнопку "поделиться" для каждого url: `http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com/1` , `http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com/2` и т.д.